# iPhone media query not directing to mobile stylesheet

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I am testing a mobile version of my site and have set up a new mobile.css file and am using the following code to redirect to it. (style.css being my main 'desktop' css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device width:480px)"/>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

I am testing this on an iPhone 5 and it simply isn't showing the mobile version of the CSS I have done things like change background colour etc. to test that its working and it just shows the regular version.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query is referencing iPhone4 not iPhone5. You could use device-aspect-ratio:

```
iPhone < 5:
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}

iPhone 5:
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}

iPad:
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}
```

Or in case you want to combinate you could do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* iPhone only */
}
```